# say without newline in Raku

Tags: raku

I want to print the even numbers in a row but I can't.

```
use Terminal::ANSIColor;
# Wanna print even numbers in red
for <1 2 3 4>
{ $_ %2 == 0 ?? say color('red'),$_,color('reset') !! say $_ }
```

`printf`  doesn't seem to work with the `Terminal::ANSIColor` directives and `put` doesn't work either.

Is there any switch to `say` which makes it print without newline? How to print those  `Terminal::ANSIColor` formatted sections in a row?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`say` is basically defined as:

```raku
sub say ( +@_ ) {
    for @_ {
        $*OUT.print( $_.gist )
    }

    $*OUT.print( $*OUT.nl-out );
}
```

If you don't want the newline, you can either change the value of `$*OUT.nl-out` or use `print` and `gist`.

```raku
say $_;

print $_.gist;
```

In many cases the result of calling `.gist` is the same as `.Str`. Which means you don't even need to call `.gist`.

```raku
use Terminal::ANSIColor;
# Wanna print even numbers in red
for <1 2 3 4> {
    $_ %% 2 ?? print color('red'), $_, color('reset') !! print $_
}
```

(Note that I used the evenly divisible by operator `%%`.)

---

`say` is for humans, which is why it uses `.gist` and adds the newline.

If you want more fine-grained control, don't use `say`. Use `print` or `put` instead.

Comment: This works but on Emacs Shell I have to add `say ""`at the end of the code. Otherwise it doesn't work (on Emacs Shell)

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen Presumably Emacs is waiting for the newline character. It probably would make more sense to use `put()` instead.

Comment: Sorry, this answer sounds a bit complicated for the question. But thanks for the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Use `print` instead of `say`:

`print color('red')`

or

`print 'red'`